# update magento products details through new "attribute value" by uploading in excel sheet

Tags: attributes, csv, importexport

we uploaded some 200 products, we created "attribute" = "size" and we have to update the value of

"size" for all 200 products. we are planning to update through excel sheet in .csv format.

what is the method we have to follow in excel sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add size attribute to your Attribute Sets
2. System -> Import/Export -> Export -> Entity Type: Products -> Continue
3. Download the Products CSV
4. Open the CSV file, search for "size" column
5. Enter the values for Size Column (if it's a dropdown attribute, then values similar to options)
6. Save the CSV file
7. System -> Import/Export -> Import -> Select the edited CSV File to Import -> Check Data
8. if "File is valid!", Import

Comment: is we have to use  "skip" option if we want to enter only size? before clicking on continue?

Comment: No, nothing to skip!

Comment: the step what you mentioned is to check file is valid or not, right? i am getting problem

"image doest't exists".... please give solution for this....

Comment: In the CSV file, did you change anything, except entering size fields?
Check the CSV file, search "image" and check

Comment: is there any option like we have to enter only sku and size and upload the csv file?

Comment: this is error i got :

Required attribute 'status' has an empty value in rows: 1, 8, 15, 22, 29, 36, 43
Required attribute 'media_gallery' has an empty value in rows: 1, 8, 15, 22, 29, 36, 43, 50, 60, 68, 75, 87
Orphan rows that will be skipped due default row errors in rows: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93

Comment: I think you might have done something wrong in CSV,
After downloading the CSV, select All, Format -> Auto Fit Column Width
Then search size column and then under this size field, add sizes for each products

Comment: using ctrl + F , i searched only for size and entered the values, but i am getting above errors.

Comment: Send me the edited CSV

Comment: hi, i created new profile with "import all size" and updated using sku and size, it's updated.

thanks a lot for your support....